# Twitter gem will only send from production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I am using twitter gem 4.8.1 http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter

It will not send stuff locally for some reason (all credentials the same and set up) saying "unable to verify your credentials" ... when the code is pushed to Heroku though it tweets with no problem.

Any reason for this? Would be nice to test out stuff locally with the gem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually sites like Twitter or Facebook require that you register the domain you will use when publishing.  If you registered www.mydomain.com with Twitter, that is the only domain it will accept connections from.

So you will need your Tweets to come from the website you entered here:
https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new